# Cmake: Not finding Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

I have a library requiring Python 2.7. Therefore my Cmake looks like:

```
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 2.7)
find_package(PythonInterp 2.7 EXACT)
```

This fails with:

```
Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "3.6.8", but required is exact version "2.7" (found /usr/bin/python3)
```

On my system, I have a few Python versions installed (2.7, 3.6, and others):

```
$ which python 
/usr/bin/python

$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2

$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ which python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6
```

I don't have any aliases in .bashrc setup or anything like that... If you enter `python`, `python2`, or `python2.7` on the command prompt, you WILL get the `python2.7` interpreter.

In trying to debug this issue, I looked into the the `FindPythonInterp.cmake` file to see where the logic is failing, and it seems that the issue lies in this line:

```
find_program(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE NAMES ${_Python_NAMES})
```

Specifically, if edit that cmake file to say

```
find_program(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE NAMES ${_Python_NAMES})
message(STATUS "find_program(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE NAMES ${_Python_NAMES})")
message(STATUS "found ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
```

and reload my project, I see the output

```
-- find_program(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE NAMES python2.7;python2)
-- found /usr/bin/python3
```

Which does not make sense to me... It seems that I am requesting that Cmake find `python2`, but it is returning `python3`, even though there are exact matches for the thing I am requesting.

Could somebody shed light on this... How would I modify or replace that `find_program` command to get the correct binary?

Answer (score 1):

Oops. I simply needed to clear out the Cmake cache.

In trying to debug some Python issues I removed and reinstalled `python2`. When I create the build folder, `python2` was not installed. So to fix, I simply removed the build folder and recreated it.

Comment: For other people: explicitely setting PYTHON_EXECUTABLE when calling cmake also helps to make sure the correct version is used. (Useful for example if some library calls `find_package(PythonInterp)` without specifying a version)

Comment: I was aware of that, but I wanted to avoid that because the project should be usable by multiple people on our team working on different systems (mac, ubuntu, windows), and that would not be portable.